# Decoding from "Base64" format to "ASCII" string

Tags: python, json, python-requests, base64, decode

I'm new to python and I need your help. I need to decode the request returns a JSON that contains an Array of Strings in Base64 format.

Return example:

```
{'doc': ['PHByb2NFdmVudG9DVGUgdmVyc2FvPSIzLjAwIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5wb3J0YWxmaXNjYWwuaW5mLmJyL2N0ZSI','PFRyYW5zZm9ybSBBbGdvcml0aG09Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnL1RSLzIwMDEvUkVDLXhtb','C1jMTRuLTIwMDEwMzE1IiAvPjwvVHJhbnNmb3Jtcz48RGlnZXN0TWV0aG9kIEFsZ29yaXRob']
```

How would I do it? I've tried looking for solutions in many answers here on the forum and none seem to have worked.

So far my code looks like this:

```
data= json.dumps(data)

response = requests.post('https://api.sieg.com/aws/api-xml-search.ashx',data=data)

arq = json.load(io.BytesIO(response.content))

print(arq)
```

Comment: In general, base64 is used to encode binary data to ASCII.  There's no guarantee that decoding it will produce valid text data.

Comment: Can you use Python's builtin base64 module? https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#module-base64

Comment: simpler  `arq = response.json()` and `post( ... json=data)` without `json.dump()`